# Tire Speed Rating Naming Convention

Tags: tires

According to an answer on [this page](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/24332/what-does-the-letter-at-the-end-of-a-tire-code-signify) the speed ratings that can appear on the end of a tire specification (like "195/65R15 91 **V**") include *almost* all of the letters of the alphalphabet in *almost* the correct order...

```
A1-A8 - Steps from 3 mph to 25 mph
B - Up to 31 mph
C - Up to 37 mph
D - Up to 40 mph
E - Up to 43 mph
F - Up to 50 mph
G - Up to 56 mph
J - Up to 62 mph
K - Up to 68 mph
L - Up to 75 mph
M - Up to 81 mph
N - Up to 87 mph
P - Up to 94 mph
Q - Up to 100 mph
R - Up to 106 mph
S - Up to 112 mph
T - Up to 118 mph
U - Up to 124 mph
H - Up to 130 mph
V - Up to 149 mph
W - Up to 168 mph
Y - Up to 186 mph
Z - 149 mph and over
```

***Why are not all of the letters in the alphabet included and why is one of the letters, H, in the wrong order?***

Comment: Are you asking why the letters aren't in alphabetical order? I'm just trying to understand.

Comment: @Paulster2 I have edited my question. Sorry it wasn't very clear before.

Comment: Thanks! And I think @JPhi1618 answered about as good as anyone can :D

Comment: @Paulster2 That is a fair point.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't have and sources for this, so please, post 'em if you got 'em, but it's my understanding that **H** was originally used to designate either **H**ighway rated tire or **H**igh speed.  Even I'm not clear on this...

Also, the letters **I** and **O** are commonly left out of lettering schemes because of their cousins, the numbers 1 and 0.

And to speculate further, **X** is missing because before standard, metric tire sizes, the X appeared as a separator between the tire height and width like: 29.0"**x** 9.3".

Comment: That would explain the missing I and O, but surely logic would suggest that X would also have a speed rating? Considering that the rest of the alphabet does!

Comment: X is being reserved for when a tire with an e**X**treme enough speed rating is manufactured.

Comment: That sounds feasible. It would just be nice to know how that originated or who came up with it or when. Maybe that is just me.

Comment: @JPhi1618 vote, not upvote ;)

Comment: Yeah sure, I'm relatively new around here so I'm still getting used to the best practises on Stack Exchange. Thanks for the advise. @Zaid Good point!

Comment: You're not too new to be able to chat.  Come [on over to the chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop) with any questions like that, or just to... chat.

Comment: Indeed.  What @JPhi1618 said.  let the question stew a bit so you increase the possibility of multiple answers...but feel free to vote on the answers.  Just hold back a bit on awarding the correct answer.   :-)

Comment: Good advise I'll bear that in mind on my posts in the future

Comment: Very Very Good Answer !!